# Minecraft PE v0.10.4 for iPhone not saving

Tags: technical-issues, ios, minecraft-bedrock-edition

My son's iPhone 4 will no longer save any changes he makes to worlds. He has all the updates and has even tried deleting the entire app and reinstalling it.

There is plenty of storage space on the phone. The rest of the family have the same version, although on iPhone 5, and have had no problems.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score -2):

It could be another bug. Write a report to moaning. It could also be a problem with his phone